# Enabling the Scrollbar inside textView after changing the font size on an Android Phone

Tags: java, android, xml

This issue is happening when I enlarge the font on my device and after that I am no longer seeing Vertical Scrollbar inside my textview. The Scrollbar appears when I change the font size back to small. Here is how my xml layout look like:

1. ```
               <ScrollView
                   android:id="@+id/MyScrollView"
                   android:layout_height="150px"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent">
               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/title"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  android:text="xxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasd."
                   android:textSize="24sp"
                   android:layout_margin="20dp"
                   android:ellipsize="marquee"
                   android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                   android:maxLines = "20"
                   android:gravity="bottom"
                   android:scrollbars="vertical"
                   android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
                   android:textColor="#676767" />
               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/tv_link"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:layout_margin="5dp"
                   android:padding="5dp"
                   android:textSize="24sp"
                   android:text="Enroll Now"
                   android:textColor="#FF0C7CC0" />
               </ScrollView>
   ```

   The code works fine but as soon as I changed the font size on my device the Scrollbar disappears

   2. And here is what I do inside my Activity class:

      ```
          ScrollView scroller = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
          TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
          tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
      ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a layout which will contain your textviews, scrollview can't control multiple views directly. Scrollview can only contain single view, you can do it like this:

```
  <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/MyScrollView"
                android:layout_height="150px"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
          <RealtiveLayout
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  android:text="xxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasdxxasdasdasd."
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:maxLines = "20"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
                android:textColor="#676767" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_link"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:text="Enroll Now"
                android:textColor="#FF0C7CC0" />
</RealtiveLayout>
            </ScrollView>
```

Comment: try removing scrollbar style, also there is no tv_title , it is title correct it